# Centos 7.1 updated to 7.2 with no login screen (gstreamer)

Tags: centos

I have updated Centos 7.1 to 7.2 today but excluded the gstreamer package since there was a conflict (package from epel repo)

I failed to realize that the update was a version upgrade and failed to understand the use of this package. As a result i have updated to 7.2 but there is no login screen. Is there another way to login and resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me on my pc, run from a virtual console:

```
yum remove gstreamer1-vaapi
yum update
reboot
```

The login screen is then ok